# Cannot disable IPv6 Autoconf and Privacy Extensions, but sysctl values are set to disable it

Tags: networking, 20.04, ipv6, dhcpv6

## Why I cannot disable IPv6 autoconfiguration even if the sysctl values are set to this?

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I am unclear about, I found that netplan needed an explicit configuration for accept_ra regardless of what was set in sysctl values, for example:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      accept-ra: false
      addresses:
        - xxx.xxx.xx.xx/22
```

And apply the new config with `netplan try`. No reboot was required.

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 but I assume 20.04 would be the same.

Comment: This works, thanks! Also @Seolh: should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Netplan practically serves as a frontend to `sysctl` and `ip`. As such, it overrides sysctl values when applying a Netplan configuration file; you will find that your sysctl changes are overwritten after running `netplan apply|try`. The active sysctl values are only used when relevant, i.e. when assigning/soliciting addresses. As such, manually overwriting the sysctl values as you wish won't have any effect until the system solicits/assigns new addresses or attempts to renew existing addresses, such as when an address's "valid lifetime" elapses.

Comment: Also, setting `accept-ra: false` requires you to statically assign not only the address and prefix length, but also the address of the gateway, so it is usually undesirable from the perspective of resulting in an increased admin burden.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Netplan (which Ubuntu does by default since Ubuntu 18.04) and just want to disable privacy addresses (RFC 8981, previous RFC 4941), then in your Netplan configuration file (e.g. `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`), set the `ipv6-privacy` parameter to `false`/`no` for the network interface in question, such as in the following example:

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      accept-ra: yes
      ipv6-privacy: no
```

If you neither want to use SLAAC in response to receipt of an RA, nor DHCPv6, then you should set `accept-ra` to `false`/`no` instead. You will then have to set addresses statically via [the `addresses` list](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types), and routes manually via [the `routes` object](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/#default-routes).

If you want to use receipt of an RA to set routes, but not to set addresses via SLAAC, then you should leave `accept-ra` unspecified entirely and rely on sysctl to configure the desired behaviour; see the documentation (from the section that the first link above points to, emphasis mine):

> - `accept-ra` (boolean)
>
> Accept Router Advertisement that would have the kernel configure IPv6 by itself. When enabled, accept Router Advertisements. When disabled, do not respond to Router Advertisements. ***If unset use the host kernel default setting.***